# How to detect when client state drifts from server state?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, synchronization

I'm obviously talking about an authoritative server to which client sends commands and gets state updates.

My question is when I get a position update and know how many milliseconds ago it was generated on the server **how do I detect and fix the drift?**

I'm currently just blocking the client from going too far away from the last update position by smoothly moving him towards that position. Which works fine on connections with low ping, but wont work with 200+ ping.

Comment: What type of game is this? The "best practices" answer for an rts is different than an fps for instance.

Comment: @AlanWolfe I need something that would work for RPG characters.

Comment: Real time combat or turn based?

Comment: @AlanWolfe It's plain old RPG networking, you press ASDW and character moves on the screen, simple as that. If you have any more questions just imagine I'm making WOW.

Comment: Yeah that's a tough question.  I would say either leash the player like you are, or if the latency is bad enough, maybe drop them from the server.

Comment: @AlanWolfe If you don't have an answer why are even commenting here? Anyway I know this can be done, because there are games that do this well. So I'm just going to experiment.

Comment: There's multiple ways to solve it, the right one is really going to be an opinion based on how you want it to behave.  On the fear engine at monolith we leashed, like you are doing. On StarCraft, since we have a lockstep simulation, all players have to wait.  Not sure what wow does exactly, but I've seen evidence of leashing while playing with network issues.

Comment: @AlanWolfe Obviously you wont let the player go too far from the position sent from server, but you cannot alter the simulation on the client if you can't calculate the drift.  
My idea is to remember past positions of the player (from few hundred milliseconds ago) and when server sends update (which contains the time when it was generated on the server) you compare it to corresponding past position and apply the fix to the current position.

Comment: What about letting him doing what he wants (client prediction) and then applying entity interpolation when there is a drift.